# Sort multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array, fetched from an SQL query. It looks like this:

```
$CIKK[$j]["vonalkod"]
$CIKK[$j]["kiadva"]
$CIKK[$j]["nev"]
$CIKK[$j]["hatarido"]
```

Can I sort `$CIKK` based on the value of its `["vonalkod"]`?

Comment: Yes you can, look at the usort() or array_multisort() functions

Comment: You could check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value.

Comment: Why not `ORDER BY vonalkod` directly in SQL?

Comment: Because I use 2 SQL queries to fill up $CIKK. Also, one of these has multiple INNER JOINs.

Answer (score 1):

you use this function

```
function sort_multi($array, $column, $method) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
        $narray[$key] = $row[$column];
    }
    array_multisort($narray, $method, $array);
    return $array;
}

$myarray = sort_multi($CIKK , 'vonalkod' , SORT_DESC)
```

i'm using array_multisort in http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

the $method will take `SORT_DESC` or `SORT_ASC`